# How do I make Espresso wait until Data Binding has updated the View with the data-model?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-databinding

I am running Espresso tests on my Android application. The test is flaky. It can reliable assert that the data-model is updated. My problem is that the ViewMatchers can't match the same value in the View because the ViewDataBinding has not yet updated the Views. (At least most of the time the test runs. )

Is there such a thing as an IdlingResource that becomes idle when the ViewDataBinding has no pending changes on the view?

My work-around is a combination of calling executePendingBindings() and a small Thread.sleep(...)

Comment: `executePendingBindings` should be enough: the binding will be executed immediately when calling that method, and not during the next frame of `Choreographer`

Comment: That was my initial thought as well. But it turns out the test runs on the AndroidJUnit thread and executePendingBindings must run on the MainThread. Scheduling it on the Main is not fast or blocking enough for a failing assert on the AndroidJUnit thread.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am have a similar issue where during espresso tests wrong values are passed to the databinding, but if I add a break point and wait for a moment it will send the correct values, the views will be correctly binded and espresso will find the view

Comment: Only a horrible SystemClock.sleep(...) currently

Comment: I end up with the ever green Thread.sleep(..) as well. I guess data binding team and espresso team needs to work together to solve this using an internal idle generator.

Comment: This bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220247  mentions about workaround using reflection. But I could not get it to work. Anyone succeeded?

Comment: @rpattabi I've applied the solution in the answer and seen it work. At least in the current (2.2.2) version of Espresso that I am now using.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Espresso does `waitForIdle` before executing view checks. `waitForIdle` goes thought `IdlingRegistry` and waits until every `IdlingResource` is idle.

`LoopingIdlingResource` is used in Espresso by default. It waits until looper doesn't have messages in queue, which means that it is idle.

However `DataBinding` uses different approach to schedule an update, it uses `Choreographer.postFrameCallback`. So updates are not posted into looper queue and Espresso will not wait for them.

In such cases you should register your own [`IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource). You can find in `googlesamples/android-architecture-components` nice sample how to implement custom [`DataBindingIdlingResource`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/7f861fd45d158e6277a3c35163c7f663e135b2cf/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/DataBindingIdlingResource.kt) and [`DataBindingIdlingResourceRule`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/7f861fd45d158e6277a3c35163c7f663e135b2cf/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/DataBindingIdlingResourceRule.kt) that will sets the idle resource before executing tests.

So you have to copy these classes [`DataBindingIdlingResourceRule`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/7f861fd45d158e6277a3c35163c7f663e135b2cf/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/DataBindingIdlingResourceRule.kt) and [`DataBindingIdlingResource`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/7f861fd45d158e6277a3c35163c7f663e135b2cf/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/DataBindingIdlingResource.kt) into your tests.

And add the following rule into your test class:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val dataBindingIdlingResourceRule = DataBindingIdlingResourceRule(activityRule)
```

Comment: I looking for this class for Java file but everywhere has Kotlin file. further this app is make by fragment but my application is make by activity

Comment: We're tracking a better solution to this in https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/317

Comment: This is now outdated, because the example classes use the now deprecated `ActivityRule` instead of the new `ActivityScenario`

Answer (score 6):

*Edit*: This is an old answer. Please use Roshak's

The bug report mentioned using reflection to change `ViewDataBinding.USE_CHOREOGRAPHER` to `false` for the tests, so here is the solution I came up with:

```
public static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField;
    try {
        modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("accessFlags");
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        //This is an emulator JVM  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    }
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, newValue);
}
```

Then, just define an `ActivityTestRule` for the Activity under test, and override its `beforeActivityLaunched()`. It is necessary to do this before the activity is launched (as opposed to in a `@Before` annotation) because `ViewDataBinding` will initialize a `Looper` if it doesn't use `CHOREOGRAPHER`.

```
@Override
protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
    super.beforeActivityLaunched();
    //Because we are using data-binding, we avoid using CHOREOGRAPHER
    try {
        ReflectionUtils.setFinalStatic(
           ViewDataBinding.class.getDeclaredField("USE_CHOREOGRAPHER"), false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This way, you can get rid of that `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This fails with NoSuchFieldException for "accessFlags". But I see accessFlags on Field class of Android. Not sure why it fails for me. I ran it on lollipop emulator.

Comment: @rpattabi You could try "modifiers" before "accessFlags" as well, as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220247#c4). Let me know if that works.
I should have noted that this solution worked when using an actual device, so it would make sense it would fail when running the tests inside an emulator jvm.

Comment: I wrote the info you provided in the link :--) "modifiers" is for desktop jvm and "accessFlags" is for android jvm. Neither of them work for me.

Comment: I checked it on actual device, no exception, yet not clear if this makes espresso wait for data binding.

Comment: @rpattabi I will modify my answer to include the case of running the test on desktop jvm.

Comment: "This fails with NoSuchFieldException for "accessFlags". But I see accessFlags on Field class of Android."

Same on a Nexus 7 running Android 5.1.1

Comment: @Rene Can you mention that on the original AOSP issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220247? They might have an explanation for that