# Android Espresso not matching with text, even though it's right there - An issue with "swipeRight" and "swipeLeft"

Tags: android, android-espresso

**Update:** So I left out that this view is inside a ViewPager. It turns out my issue was the interpretation of "swipeLeft" and "swipeRight". The reason I missed this for so long is because I would manually run through the steps by hand, and what I thought of as "swipeRight" didn't match what Espresso thinks of as swiping right. So I didn't see the issue happening until I threw in a bunch of sleeps around my code so I could see it go in slow motion. That's when I realized it was going the wrong direction. So really, this whole issue is because of that. Oops. Not sure what to do with this question, since I technically can answer it myself but it's so far from being related to what the post is about because I left out the ViewPager bits.

**Original:**

I'm doing a pretty straightforward check for text and it doesn't want to pass.

```
onView(withText("My text")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.

Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user

Got: "CustomTextView{id=2131756070, res-name=label_name, visibility=**VISIBLE**, width=506, height=53, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=220.0, y=375.0, text=**My text**, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

And here's the layout code:

```
<snip.snip.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/label_name"
                    style="@style/typographyH4Subheading"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.nameLabel}"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Any idea what could cause this to not match?

Comment: Can you show the layout xml with this `textview` where this case is failing?

Comment: @Vishu Updated with the layout code

Comment: I think is problem with data binding can you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703567/how-do-i-make-espresso-wait-until-data-binding-has-updated-the-view-with-the-dat

Answer (score 0):

Is the view actually visible on the disaplay? If it's out of viewport and you need to scroll for example `isDisplayed()` will fail.
Another problem might be that some parent of the given view has invisible or gone visibility.

You can try `.check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));` to cover the first case and `isVisible` from this [samples](https://gist.github.com/elevenetc/8038fe98bc603b91b288) to cover the second.

And do you have only one view with given text?

Comment: It's definitely visible on the display. Without scrolling, it's about dead center of my device.

Comment: try to change to `android:text="My text"`, will it work?

Comment: It appears I was mistaken. I was seeing it when I did it manually, but my tests were not doing what I expected and it just happened too fast for me to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Saw your update but if you still want to `swipe` you should try
`ViewPagerActions.scrollRight()` it looks very similar to `swipeRight()` but it is what I was able to get my viewpager to swipe correctly