# Espresso test fails due to Data binding

Tags: android, android-espresso

This is my viewmodel class :

```
class MainViewModel(
    private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider,
    private val api : StorytelService
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _posts = MutableLiveData<List<Post>>()
    val posts: LiveData<List<Post>>
        get() = _posts

    private val _status = MutableLiveData<Status>()
    val status: LiveData<Status>
        get() = _status

    init {
        showPhotos()
    }

    fun showPhotos() {
        EspressoIdlingResource.increment() // App is busy until further notice
        _status.postValue(Status.LOADING)
        compositeDisposable.add(api.getPhotos()
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
            .doFinally {
                if (!EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.isIdleNow) {
                    EspressoIdlingResource.decrement() // Set app as idle.
                }
            }
            .subscribe({
                _status.postValue(Status.SUCCESS)
                showPosts(it)
            }) {
                _status.postValue(Status.ERROR)
                Timber.e(it)
            })
    }

    private fun showPosts(networkPhotos: List<NetworkPhoto>) {
        EspressoIdlingResource.increment() // App is busy until further notice
        _status.postValue(Status.LOADING)
        compositeDisposable.add(api.getPosts()
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
            .doFinally {
                if (!EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.isIdleNow) {
                    EspressoIdlingResource.decrement() // Set app as idle.
                }
            }
            .subscribe({ networkPosts ->
                _status.postValue(Status.SUCCESS)
                _posts.postValue(
                    PostAndImages(networkPosts, networkPhotos).asDomaineModel()
                )
            }) {
                _status.postValue(Status.ERROR)
                Timber.e(it)
            })
    }
```

This is my recyclerView in layout :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:showData="@{vm.status}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/post_item" />
```

And here is binding adapter :

```
@BindingAdapter("showData")
fun View.showData(status: Status) {
    visibility = if (status == Status.SUCCESS) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

As you notice I am using EspressoIdlingResource, but when I run following espresso test, it fails :

```
    @Test
    fun shouldBeAbleToLoadList() {
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

If I add Thread.sleep(5000) in the beginning of the test, it works. How to resolve it?

Comment: Is `EspressoIdlingResource` a custom class? Did you forget to register the idling resource before the test runs?

Comment: No I did not forget, you can look at it : https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/storytel/src/master/

Comment: It looks like you have post animation, have you tried turning off the animation on device? And also if you're using databinding, this answer maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703567/how-do-i-make-espresso-wait-until-data-binding-has-updated-the-view-with-the-dat

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible with `Idling Resource` however they are a little bit tedious.

I've just updated an old viewMatcher code:

```
/**
 * Perform action of waiting for a specific view id to be displayed.
 * @param viewId The id of the view to wait for.
 * @param millis The timeout of until when to wait for.
 */
public static ViewAction waitDisplayed(final int viewId, final long millis) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "wait for a specific view with id <" + viewId + "> has been displayed during " + millis + " millis.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + millis;
            final Matcher<View> matchId = withId(viewId);
            final Matcher<View> matchDisplayed = isDisplayed();

            do {
                for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                    if (matchId.matches(child) && matchDisplayed.matches(child)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            // timeout happens
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
```

then you should only do:

```
@Test
    fun shouldBeAbleToLoadList() {
        onView(isRoot()).perform(waitDisplayed(R.id.recycler_view, 5000));
    }
```

the 5000 is a timeout of 5 secs (5000 millis), you can change it if you want to.

After `waitDisplayed` is executed it could happen that the element is shown or the timeout has been reached. In the last case an `Exception` will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks. This is a working solution. Can I ask you where did you find it?

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct or mark the answer as useful if it works for you. I've just adapted the `waitId` matcher of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796132/android-espresso-wait-for-text-to-appear

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an `Idling Resource` for the binding.
You can check [Android Architecture Components sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/dd06d9accc6e6e53f06b87546127adf344191478/GithubBrowserSample) which have a similar implementation. Here's what you will need to look for:

1. Firstly, you will need to add an `Idling Resource` class which checks if there are any bindings pending (you can find an implementation [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/4a36ccba9b3fd471b5ca1167da5c0c3d61cdd2c9/LiveDataSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/livedata/DataBindingIdlingResource.kt))
2. Now you can create a rule which will automatically register/unregister `Idling Resource` for you (you can find an implementation [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/17c315a050745c61ae8e79000bc0251305bd148b/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/DataBindingIdlingResourceRule.kt)).
3. And now you can add this rule to your test and check if it works (sample test implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/dd06d9accc6e6e53f06b87546127adf344191478/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/ui/search/SearchFragmentTest.kt)).

Comment: I have followed you instruction, but it still fails. Could you please look at : https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/storytel/src/Espresso/ and tell me why?